# Is a Laplace Transformation an example of a Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-transformations, laplace-transform

I am in an introductory linear algebra course and have already taken differential equations.

In my textbook (David Lay's Linear Algebra and it's Applications) Lay states that to show something is a linear transformation you must show two properties.

$\mathcal{L}\{f(x)+g(x)\}=\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}+\mathcal{L}\{g(x)\}$

and

$c*\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}=\mathcal{L}\{c*f(x)\}$

I feel like I've shown this to be true on my own but I have no way of checking. My assumption is that it has to be a linear transformation, if it's being used to solve linear ordinary differential equations but I haven't seen this question asked and I can't find any literature on it. I've been able to find out that it is a linear operator which appears to be equivalent statement to saying that it is a linear transformation but I'm unsure.

Comment: Compute $L(f)+L(g)$. Compute $L(f+g)$. Compare. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unrolling the definition:
$\mathcal L(f+g)(s)=\int_\mathbb R e^{-st}\left(f(t)+g(t)\right)dt=\int_\mathbb R e^{-st}f(t)dt+\int_\mathbb Re^{-st}g(t)dt=\mathcal Lf(s)+\mathcal Lg(s)$.

And

$$
\mathcal L(cf)(s)=\int_\mathbb Re^{-st} (cf(t))dt=c\int_\mathbb Re^{-st} (f(t))dt=c\mathcal L(f)(s).
$$